# How to set Inkscape to save as eps and svg format at the same time?

Tags: inkscape

I am using Inkscape to draw. I want to save the picture as an `eps` picture for use in the paper, but I often find that some details need to be modified, so I also want to keep the `svg` format. So after every modification, I have to save it in `svg` and `eps` format. Is there a quick way to save it directly in these two formats by default and prevent me from doing so many operations every time?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not as far as I know, but Inkscape can open EPS files for editing.

Comment: But it prompted me that I might lose data and suggested that I save it in svg format.

Comment: Sure, but if you are exporting simple vectors with fills and strokes you shouldn't have any problems. Just note that EPS doesn't support things like transparency or effects.  I'd suggest you perhaps try editing the EPS, and if there are any problems doing so, you may need to save the SVG for editing purposes.

Comment: I found that my font cannot be changed in eps format. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm . . . If you have some editable text in the SVG, then it should still be editable in the EPS. I just tried it and it seems to work in Inkscape 1.0. The formatting can sometimes get a bit messed up if you start trying to insert letters or change just part of a word, but you could put the cursor in the text box and delete and retype everything. Of course this might not be practical in some instances. If it's problematic, then save the SVG for editing.

Comment: Note: there's a shortcut to save an SVG if you already saved it once. Just hit CTRL+S.